# what median_unsafe in C++ mean

Tags: c++, vector

I run into a C++ code:

```
    vector<double> PITs;
    if(PITs.size() > 0) PIT = util::median_unsafe(PITs);
```

What is mean by `util::median_unsafe`, why I cant find it in C++ reference? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because it is not a part of C++ standard library. It is probably something from another part of the code you have. If you use some IDE it probably supports something like "GoTo Declaration/Definition", so you might be able to find out where that function comes from.

Comment: It probably does. But since i have no idea what PITs is i cannot be sure, it might as well do something completely different. You will have to find the implementation of the fucntion or some documentation for it.